# why would relative path not work for src in scripts?

Tags: html, path

I am running a simple HTTP server using python. I have an HTML file with the following script tag:

```
<script src="../../build/react.js"></script>
```

The file is present in the right place if the relative URL is followed, but both Chrome and Firefox, look for base/build/react.js instead of base/../../build/react.js.

I remove the relative path, and it works fine as expected. Why are the relative paths not working?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps could you define "base"?

My answer assumes that "base" is the "base URL/domain" of your website:

e.g. `base == http://www.google.com/`

The base directory is essentially acting as the root of your directory... accessing the parent of the root directory is a logical fallacy (a root has no parent). When you seek the parent of a root directory, most programs will simply return the root.

For example, I'm assuming your site has the following layout:

`www.google.com/
├── css/
│   └── theme.css
├── js/
│   └── jquery.js
└── html/
    └── home.html`

Suppose `home.html` uses the following code:

`<link href="../css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="../../js/jquery.js"></script>`

Because the parent directory of `html/` is the root directory, both will translate to:

`www.google.com/css/theme.css
www.google.com/js/jquery.js`